# how can I make a modal box to show a full php page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a model box designed in jquery on one of my pages, I wonder if it is possible to make this modal show a full dynamic php page?

Comment: Where is your code? Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: you mean you want to display a page generated via php in a **modal** box ?

Comment: yes, it is possible, you will need to load the content via "ajax".

Comment: My code only includes the model and some small php parts, nothing special. Is there any option to present a PHP page on a modal box?

Comment: @singebatteur yes that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: Yes you can set the content dynamical by sending a ajax request to the page you want to show and on success add the response content as your modal box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `load()` function, which is very easy to use, and well documented : http://api.jquery.com/load/ . it loads a page in the selected element, your modal's body for example, just calling a url.

Comment: This is the correct answer in my opinion. We should always avoid iframes. 
With the `load()` function you can load the php document into the DOM element that you select in jQuery. 
Consider also using Ajax, you can GET information from a PHP document that returns a JSON.

Comment: you can return partial templates, Its so nice and easy ! And use a callback !

Comment: Yes! I use `load()` combining PHP and Handlebars!

Answer (score 0):

Use iframe for modal box

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Trigger Modal in iFrame</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <iframe src="/user/dashboard" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>  
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Iframe src will have your dynamic page.

Comment: I discourage the use of Iframe

Answer (score 0):

Include bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js

eg:,

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="your_url content to show" data-target="#myModal">Click</a>

<div id="#myModal"></div>
```

Reference-http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `load()` like this,

**jQuery part**

```
<!-- Load jQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- A button on the page -->
<body>
    <button>Fetch Page</button>
</body>

<!--
1. Attach click event to 'button' with jQuery on()
2. Create a modal box dynamically with append()
3. Load 'the_dynamic_page.php' with jQuery load()
-->
<script>
$('body').on('click','button',function(){
    $('body').append("<div id='modal_box' style='border:1px solid #999;position:fixed;top:50%;left:45%;padding:0 0.75%;font-family:Calibri,Candara,Arial;'></div>");
    $('#modal_box').load('the_dynamic_page.php');
});
</script>
```

**the_dynamic_page.php**

This page could simply display a text like 'Im in a Modal Box!' or something from db.